# Spark Executor calculation, Cluster Size and Exit status 143 error

Tags: apache-spark

I have 3gb of data 400000 rows in a table.
I need to create GCP data proc cluster.

1. Require CLuster size like (1 master 3 worker with size 2 core 8 GB RAM each )
2. executor memory
3. executor memory overhead
4. executor core
5. executor intance
6. driver memory

I try apply below default config as per google

1. CLuster size like (1 master 4 worker with size 16 core 64 GB RAM each )
2. executor memory -19g
3. executor memory overhead - 2g
4. executor core - 5
5. executor intance -3
6. driver memory -2g

Still i get Exit status 143 error.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To properly answer your question, we'll need some more information here: what are you trying to do? Are you running any Spark code? If yes, edit your question to add your code. Also, you should explain what your cluster manager is (local, standalone, yarn, kubernetes, ...). It seems like you've added some lines to your question that are irrelevant (your first 6 points) or inconsistent (are you using 3 or 4 workers?) as well. [This page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) might help you to ask a good question.

Answer (score 0):

In General, it's upto us how we want to configure the Spark Executors. I would recommend to create 1 Executor per Worker Node to remove executor overheads. Keeping 75% memory reserved for the executor/driver.

Also we can create the cluster horizontally (4 - 5 Nodes of 16 GB RAM with 4 Cores) or vertically ( 1 - 2 Nodes 32 GB RAM with 8 Cores etc.). If the data is too much skewed then I would prefer to create it more vertically. But then it all depends what you're trying to achieve from the dataset and what kind of transformations you've applied.

Read it more in [here](https://docs.databricks.com/clusters/cluster-config-best-practices.html) for more information on Cluster Sizing Best Practices

P.S. For 143 Exit, Consider looking at it from a different perspective. Does it have too much of small files? Is the data too much skewed? Is there a shuffle happening while processing this dataset (refer to the Spark DAG)? This will help you clarify more on the processing speed required as per your SLA. Hope this helps.